# PayPal NVP PHP API $ACK="FAILURE"

Tags: php, api, paypal, nvp

Using PayPal NVP PHP API.  When a payment is submitted $ACK response equals "FAILURE" with the long message "THIS TRANSACTION CANNOT BE PROCESSED. PLEASE ENTER A VALID CREDIT CARD NUMBER AND TYPE.".... however the payment does go through.  I end up getting paid multiply times because of the Failure response error.  Does anybody have any experience with this?

Comment: Which API call are you making that returns this message? Regardless, I recommend you call PayPal support ASAP. You should never get a message that incorrectly reports the transaction's success.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you must somehow have duplicate API hits happening, where the first one includes all the correct details and processes the payment, but then you have one following that up which is empty and returning the error, and that's the result people are seeing on the site.

I would make sure you have logging setup of some kind so you can see all of the API requests and responses, and then when you run a test order check to see if you're getting more logs than you expect.